# Use Windows explorer to get the path to a file in python

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, explorer

How would I
1. Access windows explorer
2. Use it to to gain the path to a file. For example when I click "open" it pastes the address of the selected file into an entry box

I'm using tkinter if that helps at all.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [one link answer](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog) not worthy of a full response......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import `tkinter.filedialog` with a statement such as `from tkinter import filedialog` (3.x) or `import FileDialog as filedialog` (2.x).  This module is not properly documented in the CPython docs, nor anywhere else I know of, so read the code to determine which of the `ask...` methods you want to use.  In 3.x, the code is `Lib/tkinter/filedialog.py`.  In 2.x, `Lib/libtk/FileDialog.py`.

EDIT: From what you said, you may want either `askopenfilename` or `askopenfilenames`.  I believe these return names without opening the files.  The functions without `name` actually open the files.